# C++11 code using empty initalizer as parmeter compiles in GCC 4.8, 7, Cygwin, but not MSVS 2017

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-c++

As requested, I have a code file that compiles and runs on cygwin, but not in MSVS where an empty initalizer being used as a parameter to a templated function is okay in gcc, but not MSVS:

```
    // TestError.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//


#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class otherclass
{
public:
    T* allocated;
    otherclass(int n) { allocated = new T[n]; }
    ~otherclass() { delete[] allocated; }
};

class otherclass_accessor
{
public:
    int sz;
    otherclass_accessor(int inputSize) : sz(inputSize) {}
};

template<typename T>
class baseclass : public otherclass_accessor
{
private:
    std::vector<T*> mPointers;
public:
    T const * const * sp;
    std::vector<T> someVector;
    baseclass(std::vector<T>& someVector) : otherclass_accessor(someVector) {}
    ~baseclass() { mPointers.resize(0); }
};

class RRC : public baseclass<int>
{ 
public:
    template <typename T> RRC(otherclass<T>& a) : baseclass<void>(reinterpret_cast<otherclass<void>&>(a)) {}
    template< typename T > operator baseclass<T> const & () const { return reinterpret_cast< baseclass<T> const & >(*this); }
};

template< int N > using ARRC = std::array<RRC, N>;

template <int A>
void run_filter_multi(ARRC<A> in)
{
    std::cout << "Input Size:" << in.size() << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    run_filter_multi<0>({});
    return 0;
}
```

compiles with g++ -std=c++11 TestError.cpp -o test
and outputs:
Input Size:0

but with MSVS2017 I get error C2664:

1>------ Build started: Project: TestError, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>TestError.cpp
1>c:\users\dayd\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\testerror\testerror.cpp(53): error C2664: 'void run_filter_multi<0>(std::array)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer list' to 'std::array'
1>c:\users\dayd\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\testerror\testerror.cpp(53): note: Invalid aggregate initialization
1>Done building project "TestError.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

So - now my question is why is an empty initializer okay with g++, but not MSVS2017?  This is a watered down version where I tried to mock up what I was experiencing in a much larger project I am trying to make "cross platform".  I can't seem to think of a way around it in MSVS.  I have tried using std::vector instead of std::array, but the std::array is so pervasive in the code I inherited that trying to change all the underlying layers would be very painful, at best.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not post a complete but minimal example that exemplifies the issue and that readers can try out by simple copy and paste? U now, code not words. Actually I'm obliged to vote to close this as lacking such an example, but I think questions are generally closed too fast, before the OP has had a chance to fix things, so, please do. Fix things.

Comment: If you need a lot of time to prepare an example, perhaps post a comment that you're working on it.

Comment: Visual C++ [accepts zero-sized std::array](http://rextester.com/BKA1344). Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Voted to close as lacking example.

Comment: I see your point.  It probably is something complex that would be easier to see if I could post something that showed the problem.  I'll work on it....

Comment: Ok - I have posted a short code example that demonstrates the behavior in question in MSVS2017 and works as expected using Cygwin/g++.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues, but the big show-stopper one is this:

```
#include <array>
struct S { S(int); }; // Not default-constructible.
std::array<S, 0> x {};
```

This fails with

> error C2073: 'std::array<S,0>::_Elems': elements of partially initialized array must have a default constructor

Since C++ doesn't allow for zero-length arrays, but `std::array<T, 0>` is still supposed to work, it must be implemented using a little bit of trickery. Unfortunately MSVC's trickery is broken: it gives it a field of type `T[1]`, which then fails badly because the empty unused `T` element cannot be constructed.

The only ways around this that I see is giving `RRC` a default constructor, or avoiding `std::array<T, 0>`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was actually playing with it some more trying to clean up my example above (I threw it together) and I saw similar behavior.  I was trying to confirm that it wasn't just me and that it was a compiler issue.  I am ok at debugging things once they compile, but I have a tough time debugging compiler issues.  Just out of curiosity, where / how would you find out how MSVC behaves, etc.  Any tricks or suggestions for if I run into other things like this in the future?

Comment: @tenspd137 For issues like this, once based on the compiler output you suspect a particular problem, you can view the header files supplied with MSVC to confirm.